# jquery ajaxComplete() without dom object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ajax (via jquery) for exchanging data with a database. As the .ajaxcomplete function is always based on a jquery object with selector, is there any other way to check whether this explicit ajax request was sucessfull? The .ajax does not belong to any specific dom object like div etc. I want to use Ajax in a pure Javascript file. In this moment not associated with the specific html page. $(document).ajaxComplete() works but is not what I want

```
this.replot=function(){ 
    $(this).ajaxComplete(function() {alert('hallo');});   //here is my prob
    var that=this;
    var anfrage='anfrage= SELECT '+ this.xvaluecol+', '+this.y1valuecol+ ' FROM '+ this.tablename+ ' WHERE '+this.xvaluecol+' <=\'2010-11-06 15:00:00\' AND '+this.xvaluecol+' >=\'2010-11-06 07:00:00\'';
    $.ajax({
        url : 'getdata.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: anfrage,
        type : 'post',
        success : function(json) {
            if(String(json[0][0]).search('error')==-1)
            {
                that.data1=json;
                that.xaxismin=json[0][0];
                that.xaxismax=json[json.length-1][0];
                that.yaxsismin=parseInt(that.find_min(json));
                that.yaxismax=parseInt(that.find_max(json));
                console.log(json);
                console.log("yaxismin="+that.yaxismin);
                console.log("yaxismax="+that.yaxismax);
                //c=new Date((that.xaxismin));
                //c.setMinutes(c.getMinutes()+1441+60);
                //(c.toLocaleString());
                that.update();
                $.jqplot(that.divid,[that.data1,that.data2],that.options).replot();
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Plot nicht moeglich Fehlercode: '+json[0][1]);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you need a global `ajaxComplete` handler here. Did you try specifying a `complete` handler in your call to `$.ajax()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm prone to using `ajaxStop` over `ajaxComplete`. Not sure about all the differences though, I think it's similar.

The element you bind `ajaxComplete` to doesn't really matter. The following two snippets of code do exactly the same:

```
$("#some_element").ajaxComplete(function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

versus

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    alert($("#some_element").html());
});
```

So I think your problem can be solved by using `$(document)`.

Comment: the second fires at each ajax call, the first one only with regard to #some_element or not?

Comment: ajaxStop is always fired for every handler that is registered. It doesn't matter whether you put document or any selector, it will be fired after an ajax call. The only real difference $(document) or $(selector) makes, is that the context of using `$(this)` withing the function is different. I've never encountered anything else that changed according to the original selector to which the event is bound.

Comment: Ajax calls are never bound to items by the way, as there is nothing about an Ajax call that requires it to relate to an existing item.

Comment: ok, was a bit confusing, but now seems quite logical. can i give an ajax call an id which i can put into a variable. for example step=2? so after the event fired i get the number of the specific ajax call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you explain further?

Comment: if i have several ajax- calls how can i identify which one caused the trigger/firering of ajaxComplete? Hope you understand

Comment: In that case, I would suggest adding a 'complete' callback to each Ajax call, to easily rmemeber which is which. There is a way of adding an id to the call itself but I find it to be less maintainable in the future. I prefer to add the functions per ajax call (given a reasonable amount of different ajax calls of course).

Comment: ok, for which purpose do i use complete and sucess? thanks for your quick replies ;)

Comment: Success = all is ok. Error = something went wrong. So it's always ONE of the two that is executed. Regardless of which one, Complete is executed after that.

Answer (score 0):

When defining your ajax call you can specify a "Complete" callback. This call back gets called after all ajax calls and after success/error callbacks.

```
$.ajax({
    complete: function(){ alert('hello'); }
});
```

$.ajax also returns a promise object as of jQuery 1.5. If you are using a later version of jQuery you could also do this:

```
var jqXhr = $.ajax({ ... your code }).always(function(){ alert('hello'); });
//Or
jqXhr.always(function(){ alert('hello'); });
```

Comment: The difference with using the Complete callback is that it now only fires for this ajax call. If there are multiple different ajax calls on the page, you would have to add it to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set global event handlers for ajax requests in jQuery. You can add a dynamic property (say 'id') and identify a particular request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.id + " success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.id + " failed");
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.id + " completed");
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/"
}).id = "request1";

$.ajax({
    url: "/"
}).id = "request2";

$.ajax({
    url: "sdddqwdqwdqwd.com"
}).id = "request3";
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/3fX8b/